# Dalton's law of additive pressures

Tags: thermodynamics

In a mixture of ideal gases, if the pressure of the mixture is doubled, what happens to the partial pressure of each gas? Please explain. Thanks a lot.

We start with the expression for the pressure of a mixture
$$P_\text{mix} = \sum P_i \,,$$
where $P_i$ is the partial pressure of the $i$th gas. If $P_\text{mix}$ is doubled, what happens to each $P_i$? Are they doubled too?

Comment: We have the MathJax math rendering engine active on the site, and it is preferred to posting images of math because it is editable and agrees in size and typeface with the rest of the post. I've done this one for you. You can fine some basic help on [our formating page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help), and much more on [on various latex site](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) (MathJax's input language is approximate the same as LaTeX mathmode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $P_{\text{mix}} = P_1 +P_2 = \dfrac {m_1RT}{V} + \dfrac {m_2RT}{V} = \dfrac {mRT}{V} $ where $m_1+m2= m$

Now double the pressure by halving the volume or doubling the temperature  and the partial pressures will also double.

Comment: we don't know how the pressure has been doubled? we don't know the progress. what we know is the initial and final pressure of the mixture.

Comment: It does not matter how the pressure is double all that matters is that the amount of each constituent gas is the same.  The point is that whatever you do to $T$ of $V$ to change $P$ will be the same (term) for all the constituent gases.  Looking at that equation above the way that the pressure can be doubles is to double $\frac T V$.  That is a common term in each part of the equation for pressure.